# UINavigationBar with Higher Height above View Controller's view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to increase the navigation bar of a navigation controller at a certain point. for iOS 11 I managed to do that setting `navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true` 
But for the others iOS versions I'm doing it manually

The problem is that when I try to change the navigation bar height manually the view controller's view gets under the expanded part of the navigation bar.

This is where I do the trick:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func setupNavigationWithMenu(){
        let bounds = self.navigationBar.bounds
        let menuHeight: CGFloat = 50 //whatever height you want to add to the existing height
        let segmentedMenu = SegmentedMenu(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: bounds.height, width: bounds.width, height: menuHeight))
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        } else {

            let bounds = self.navigationBar.bounds
            self.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + menuHeight)

        }

        self.navigationBar.addSubview(segmentedMenu)

    }

}
```

And I call the the setup here:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController!.setupNavigationWithMenu()
}
```

How can I adjust my view controller's view to start after the navigation bar?

For iOS 11 it works just fine, for the others the view gets under the navigation

This is what happens when it's not iOS 11
[image: View Under the Navigation]
[image]

Comment: No... I didn't tested on iPhone X yet... although iPhone X will have iOS 11 at least

Answer (score 0):

A navigation bar has a fixed height governed by the navigation controller. The idea is to stick with that and not attempt to change it.

The "large titles" approach works only for iOS 11 because large titles are an iOS 11 innovation.

Comment: I am managing to increase the navigationBar... the problem is the view controller's view... are you saying it's impossible for others iOS to increase the navigation bar?

Comment: I'm saying it subverts Cocoa's expectations. The navigation controller is responsible for the placement of the navigation bar and the view controller's view, and you are sabotaging that.